# How to count rows each sheet and send the total value to new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

For example i have 7 sheets on workbook then i want to count all row each sheet. The total rows each sheets.

Comment: The value of total rows each sheet will display on new sheet

Comment: `Sheet.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question answered [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/489376-count-lines-multiple-sheets.html)

```
    For Each sh In Activeworkbook.Worksheets
    MsgBox "Sheet " & sh.Name & " has " & sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 & " rows"
    Next sh
```

This -1 from the rows (to exclude a header row)

Comment: Thanks. Working !!

Comment: Marked as answered :)